# Warning - Wildcard DNS may not be configured correctly

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, wordpress

I just enabled multisite in Wordpress and I get this message:

> Warning! Wildcard DNS may not be configured correctly!
>
> The installer attempted to contact a random hostname
>   (3757b5.mysite.no) on your domain. This resulted in an error message:
>   Could not open handle for fopen() to http://3757b5.mysite.no

I'm not getting these errors for single site installations, just when I enable multisite.

---

My web server is running on Ubuntu 11.1 on my **Virtual Machine** (VirtualBox).
And to be clear:  **this is on my local development computer**. It's not on a ISP server.

---

I've checked `php.ini` to see if fopen is enabled, and it is:
`allow_url_fopen = On`

The default Apache config file found in `/etc/apache2/sites-avaialble/default` looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

And the Apache config file for my site looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite/
    ServerName mysite.no
    ServerAlias *.mysite.no

 <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
 </Directory>

 <Directory /var/www/storelocator/>
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all
 </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Does anyone know what I can try to solve this issue?

**NOTE**
To access mysite.no and my subsite, I have updated my HOST file which resides on my computer (Win 7):

```
10.20.23.104       mysite.no
10.20.23.104       engelstad.mysite.no
```

Comment: Do you want or need wildcard hostnames to function?  What does the DNS configuration look like for this domain?

Comment: It is a requirement to allow wildcards in order to have WP multisite work with sub-domains. Where can I find the DNS configuration? This is on my local computer.

Comment: You only need a wildcard if you actually need to have it work with all arbitrary subdomains.  If you're only going to have a small handful of subdomains, then you certainly don't need a wildcard.  The DNS configuration for the domain depends on how you've configured it; do you own the domain in question?

Comment: @shane-madden - it's on my local computer. I'm running Virtual MAchine.

Comment: In your configuration, you have `*.mysite.no`.  Is that a placeholder for a domain name that you own?  Or is that literally what you have configured, and you're looking to have that domain point to the local Apache service for requests that come from your computer?

Comment: I've added the alias `*.mysite.no`. But normally I don't think I have to do this when I enable multisite (?).

Answer (score 3):

I believe that this is so any non-explicit subdomain will be sent to your web server where Apache assigns the request to a particular virtual host.

Create a star record if you want that ability:

```
*.mysite.no.       3600       A       [ip-address].
```

You would create the DNS record in the control panel that exists wherever you bought the mysite.no domain.

Comment: It's on my own computer. I'm running a Virtual Server.

Comment: What are you using for DNS to resolve mysite.no?

Comment: I'm using my `HOST` file (Win7). See update Q (in 1 min)

Comment: @Steven It's not possible to create a wildcard entry in the hosts file.  Ignore the warning, and create explicit entries for each subdomain that you want to use.

Comment: @shane-madden I've not added it in my HOST file. It's in my Apache2 config file for my site: `ServerAlias *.mysite.no`

Comment: @Steven Your Apache configuration does not have any bearing on name resolution.  You said you're using your hosts file; what have you added to it?

Comment: @shane-madden See my above **note**

Comment: @Steven Then for each other name that you want to use, you need to add a new entry to the hosts file.  There is no way to get that Wordpress warning to go away while using the hosts file.

Comment: @shane-madden Yes, I know. But this is before I have generated any sub-sites. This is when I enable multisite for the very first time. So it doesn't matter what I have in my HOST file (except for mysite.no). I'm trying to figure out why `wildcards` and `fopen` is failing.

Comment: Because the name cannot be resolved.  Because it's querying a ***random*** name within the domain, in an effort to verify that you've created a wildcard DNS entry; a DNS entry that does not exist and can never exist when you're using a hosts file for your name resolution.